# F# on/in SharpDevelop?

Tags: f#, mono, sharpdevelop

Is there an F# compiler (plugin?) for SharpDevelop? I use SharpDevelop on my netbook for hobby development and it would be cool to program in f# on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you install the [F# compiler](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/), SharpDevelop 3.0  automatically supports it. (Oh well. At least people will get a good answer now.)

Comment: Now that f# version 3.0 has been released, the standalone compiler is not available.  It is only available with Visual Studio Express Web 2012. Sharp Develop doesn't recognise the new version of f# either. A source code drop of f# 3.0 has happened though.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, I settled on Visual Studio Shell and the May F# CTP.

Answer (score 1):

There's a rather old (Aug 2008) [F# Plugin for MonoDevelop](http://code.google.com/p/wildart/). Read more on its [Wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/wildart/wiki/FSharpBinding).

For the F# compiler, download the xip file from the [F# May 2009 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7bb32f32-9fac-4f34-ad56-b0bda130cf00&displaylang=en) page. there are certain known issues with running it on Mono, just [search for "**`F# Mono`**"](http://www.bing.com/search?q=f%23+mono) for more info.

Comment: BTW, what's the difference between MonoDevelop and SharpDevelop?

Comment: MonoDevelop is part of the Mono project, SharpDevelop is a separate IDE implementation for .net

Answer (score 1):

Now Visual Studio 2010 supports F#. However, that doesn't include the Express editions, so if you're looking for F# IDEs for free, then there's a MonoDevelop plugin (which needs v2.6 IIRC), you can install Visual Studio Shell Integrated and add FSharp to that, or SharpDevelop. 
Of these, I'd probably recommend the Visual Studio Shell over the others as it seems to have the best integration between the editor window and the F# Console window. However, if you're interested in doing things cross-platform, then look at MonoDevelop, as you can make sure that something will work on Mono.